# Can we scrape pages that a facebook user has liked using facebook API?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Can we scrape pages that a facebook user has liked using facebook API and what API to use? This is as long as user has approved the permissions required to access their likes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/likes/

For example, with the JavaScript SDK after authorizing the user with the [user_likes](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/permissions/reference/user_likes) permission:

```
FB.api(
    "/me/likes",
    function (response) {
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
      }
    }
);
```